# append value from $this input after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple forms on my site with the same input names and therefore I use `dataString = $(this).parent().serialize();`.

The script itself works perfectly, but I wan't to append the text from the specific input field.

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.AnswerPQSubmit').click(function() {
        dataString = $(this).parent().serialize();
        var pqid = $(".pqid").val();
        var answerpq = $(".answerpq").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'postpqanswer.php',
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $(".comment"+pqid).append('<p>'+answerpq'</p>');
            }
         });
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="answerpq" class="answerpq" placeholder="Write your answer" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pqid" class="pqid" value="<?php echo $rowA['pq_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="AnswerPQSubmit" class="AnswerPQSubmit" value="Send" />
    <span class="comment<?php echo $rowA['pq_id']; ?>"></span>
</form>
```

What I have tried to do, is to give the "comment span" a unique class by adding the ID of the post at the end of "comment".

So... I'm trying to append the text from the specific input to the comment*id*. It's somewhat working, but because I use this: `dataString = $(this).parent().serialize();` this var `var pqid = $(".pqid").val();` is just finding the first pgid class in the document, instead of the one in `$this` form.

What I am looking for is something like this:

`var pqid = $(this).(".pqid").val();` I know this line is not working. but this gives you an idea of what I am looking for. I'm currently lost.

Comment: you want to append value to form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your implementation is that `$(".pqid").val()` will always return you the value of first element. You can use `.siblings()` to target siblings element.

```
var pqid = $(this).siblings(".pqid").val();
var answerpq= $(this).siblings(".answerpq").val();
```

---

However I would recommend you bind `submit` event instead of `click`.

*HTML*

```
<form class="PQSubmit" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="answerpq" class="answerpq" placeholder="Write your answer" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pqid" class="pqid" value="<?php echo $rowA['pq_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="AnswerPQSubmit" class="AnswerPQSubmit" value="Send" />
    <span class="comment comment<?php echo $rowA['pq_id']; ?>"></span>
</form>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.PQSubmit').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //cancel default action
        dataString = $(this).serialize();
        var pqid = $(this).find(".pqid").val();
        var answerpq = $(this).find(".answerpq").val();
        var commentSection = $(this).find(".comment")
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'postpqanswer.php',
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                commentSection.append('<p>'+answerpq'</p>');
            }
         });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I learned a couple of things. When I'm using `$('.PQSubmit').submit(function() {` - the page reloades though, which shouldn't happen. How is that? Thank you!

Comment: @Morten Use  `$('.PQSubmit').submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: This worked. I used `event.stopPropagation();` which didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current input value by this :

```
var pqid = $(this).parent("form").find(".pqid").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pqid = $(".pqid").val();
var answerpq = $(".answerpq").val();
```

Move the above two lines inside the success of ajax to get latest value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.AnswerPQSubmit').click(function() {
        dataString = $(this).parent().serialize();

        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'postpqanswer.php',
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                var pqid = $(".pqid").val();
                var answerpq = $(".answerpq").val();
                $(".comment"+pqid).append('<p>'+answerpq'</p>');
            }
         });
        return false;
    });
});
```